# Can't configure Gateway of last resort

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to set gateway of last resort on gns3 but it says 
( invalid input detected at '^' marker ) 
Ip route 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 192.178.1.1
Your help will appreciated

Comment: well, 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 is not a valid address. I've never seen an ip command for windows, and I get errors for it in powershell and cmd.exe, so I think you are trying to use a linux command ( ip(8) ) on windows. try somthing like 'route -p ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter Config mode from Enable mode.

```
enable
configure terminal
(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.178.1.1
```

This was tested on a base 2611 image in GNS and PacketKeeper

Comment: thats cisco IOS syntax, no? is there any reason to believe the op is configuring a cisco router?

Comment: I have tried it still it didn't work hop you know any other way to configure it thanks

Comment: Hey man thank you very much I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, Cisco IOS syntax.  No, there is reason to believe the original poster probably is not configuring a physical cisco router.  gns3.com indicates it is router emulation software.  From the FAQ: "Most users use GNS3 to emulate Cisco IOS as well as other vendors."